# Grade calculator for a project with four aspects

Tags: java, beginner

I have a program that will ask the user to input their grades for 4 different sections of a project, then tell them what their total mark is, what grade they got and how many marks away they were from the next grade. I managed to make a single loop for all inputs rather than having a loop for each individual one, but there are still quite a lot of if statements to determine what grade they got and how far away they were from the next one, and I can't figure out how to optimise it since I'm still very new to Java.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PortfolioGrade {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] words = new String[]{"Analysis", "Design", "Implementation", "Evaluation"};
        int[] marks = new int[words.length];
        for(int counter = 1; counter <= words.length; counter++) {
            System.out.println("Enter your mark for the '" + words[counter - 1] + "' part of the project: ");
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
                    marks[counter - 1] = reader.nextInt();
                    if(marks[counter - 1] < 0 || marks[counter - 1] > 25) {
                        System.out.println("Please input a number between 0 and 25.");
                        continue;
                    }
                    break;
                } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println("Please input a valid integer.");
                }
            }
        }

        int totalmark = Arrays.stream(marks).sum();
        String grade = null;
        String nextgrade = null;
        Integer marksaway = null;

        if(totalmark < 2) {
            grade = "U";
            marksaway = 2 - totalmark;
            nextgrade = "1";
        } else if(totalmark >= 2 && totalmark < 4) {
            grade = "1";
            marksaway = 4 - totalmark;
            nextgrade = "2";
        } else if(totalmark >= 4 && totalmark < 13) {
            grade = "2";
            marksaway = 13 - totalmark;
            nextgrade = "3";
        } else if(totalmark >= 13 && totalmark < 22) {
            grade = "3";
            marksaway = 22 - totalmark;
            nextgrade = "4";
        } else if(totalmark >= 22 && totalmark < 31) {
            grade = "4";
            marksaway = 31 - totalmark;
            nextgrade = "5";
        } else if(totalmark >= 31 && totalmark < 41) {
            grade = "5";
            marksaway = 41 - totalmark;
            nextgrade = "6";
        } else if(totalmark >= 41 && totalmark < 54) {
            grade = "6";
            marksaway = 54 - totalmark;
            nextgrade = "7";
        } else if(totalmark >= 54 && totalmark < 67) {
            grade = "7";
            marksaway = 67 - totalmark;
            nextgrade = "8";
        } else if(totalmark >= 67 && totalmark < 80) {
            grade = "8";
            marksaway = 80 - totalmark;
            nextgrade = "9";
        } else if(totalmark >= 80) {
            grade = "9";
        }

        System.out.println("Your total mark was " + totalmark + ".");
        System.out.println("You got a Grade " + grade + ".");
        if(grade == "9") {
            System.out.println("You achieved the highest grade!");
        } else if(marksaway == 1) {
            System.out.println("You were " + marksaway + " mark away from a Grade " + nextgrade + ".");
        } else {    
            System.out.println("You were " + marksaway + " marks away from a Grade " + nextgrade + ".");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there are no holes you can simply have an array of "breakpoints".

```
int [] steps = new int[] { 2, 4, 13, 22, 31, 41, 54, 67, 80 };
int i;

for(i=0; i<steps.length && totalmark>=steps[i]; i++);
grade = i==0 ? "U" : ""+i;
if(i<steps.length) marksaway=steps[i]-totalmark; 
nextgrade=""+(i+1);
```

Comment: Would you mind giving me a fairly simple explanation as to how this works?

Comment: The loop loops over the array and breaks out if toolmark greater the current array-entry.
I.e. totalmark=3. First loop, i is 0 and totalmark is greater than steps[0] -> continue  --  Second loop, i is 1 and totalmark is not greater than steps[1] -> break out of the loop with i=1. Set grade to "1", marksaway to steps[1]-totalmark and nextgrade to "2"

Answer (score 1):

I tidied up the first section for you a bit and then implemented the technique suggested by @Holger, all seems to work perfectly after running a few tests.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MarkCalculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] words = new String[]{"Analysis", "Design", "Implementation", "Evaluation"};
    int[] steps = { 2, 4, 13, 22, 31, 41, 54, 67, 80 };
    int[] marks = new int[4];

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); // Keep instantiation of scanner outside of loop - once is enough

    int totalmark = 0; 
    int inputMark = 0;
    int marksaway = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    String grade = "";
    String nextgrade = "";

    for(int counter = 0; counter<words.length; counter++) {
        System.out.println("Enter your mark for the '" + words[counter] + "' part of the project: ");
        try {
            do {
                inputMark = reader.nextInt();
                if(inputMark < 0 || inputMark > 25)
                    System.out.println("Please input a number between 0 and 25.");
                else
                    marks[counter] = inputMark;
            } while(inputMark < 0 || inputMark > 25);
        } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please input a valid integer.");
            reader.nextLine();
            counter--;
        }
    }

    totalmark = Arrays.stream(marks).sum();

    for(int i=0; i<steps.length && totalmark>=steps[i]; i++) {
        grade = (i==0 ? "U" : ""+i);
        if(i < steps.length) {
            marksaway = steps[(i+1)]-totalmark; 
            nextgrade = "" + (i+1);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Your total mark was " + totalmark + ".");
    System.out.println("You got a Grade " + grade + ".");
    if(grade == "9") {
        System.out.println("You achieved the highest grade!");
    } else if(marksaway == 1) {
        System.out.println("You were " + marksaway + " mark away from a Grade " + nextgrade + ".");
    } else {    
        System.out.println("You were " + marksaway + " marks away from a Grade " + nextgrade + ".");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Would a while true loop not be necessary in this case in order to skip the iteration if the user enters an invalid input?

Comment: You are totally right my mistake, my edit should fix this and avoid the ugly while(true). There is still an issue with the case when someone enters a character other than an integer, will have a look at it.

Comment: After reading the answers to the following question, I changed the catch block so that it consumes whatever invalid token have been inputted and then decrements counters so that it asks for the same grade again.  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414299/java-scanner-exception-handling